# Multitouch : Selecting hardware and software for multi-touch application

Tags: multi-touch, nui

I am trying to build an internet connected touch based device using which users can do minor editing and upload photographs to web.  The device will capture photographs using a USB based camera.

The question i have is where to find hardware for this custom requirement, i am looking for a touch screen around 24 inches in size.

Can any one recommend a reliable hardware vendor who supplies LCD/Capacitive based touchscreen.

I also thought to wait till launch of Windows 8, because it is built to support multi touch. I believe during launch of Win8 lot of hardware vendors will sell multi touch lcd monitors, which i can use.

If anyone can provide directions on this it will be a great help.

P.S > I am open to develop on any platform.

Comment: I feel this is more of a hardware question first, feel free to direct me to any other forum which is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Look at 3M monitors and infrared frames which support 4+ touches. The old ones which come with Dell monitors suck so much. Your OS of choice is Windows 7. Also consider Flash/AIR for fast development.

Comment: I have given one up rating for your answer, will research for few more days and if I dont find anything better than this i will not hesitate to mark this as an answer.  Once again thanks for your help.